# Is it possible to generate an app with different icons for iOS/Android

Tags: icons, codenameone

I'm building an App using [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) and the app icon is contained within a single 500x500 `icon.png` file which is defined in the project root.

This is convenient but I would like the styling of my icon to be different for the various OS's (Android & iOS build targets). E.g. I'd like iOS to use one icon file and Android to use another.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the `build.xml` file and replace the `icon.png` file in the relevant tasks sending the build for each platform.

E.g. for the iOS target you will see something like this within the file:

```xml
<target name="build-for-ios-device" depends="clean,copy-ios-override,copy-libs,jar,clean-override">
    <codeNameOne
        jarFile="${dist.jar}"
        displayName="${codename1.displayName}"
        packageName = "${codename1.packageName}"
        mainClassName = "${codename1.mainName}"
        version="${codename1.version}"
        icon="${codename1.icon}"
        vendor="${codename1.vendor}"
        subtitle="${codename1.secondaryTitle}"

        targetType="iphone"
        certificate="${codename1.ios.debug.certificate}"
        certPassword="${codename1.ios.debug.certificatePassword}"
        provisioningProfile="${codename1.ios.debug.provision}"
        appid="${codename1.ios.appid}"
        />
</target>
```

Just edit it to copy the iOS specific file first (assuming its named `icon-ios.png`):

```xml
<target name="build-for-ios-device" depends="clean,copy-ios-override,copy-libs,jar,clean-override">
    <copy file="icon-ios.png" tofile="icon.png" />
    <codeNameOne
        jarFile="${dist.jar}"
        displayName="${codename1.displayName}"
        packageName = "${codename1.packageName}"
        mainClassName = "${codename1.mainName}"
        version="${codename1.version}"
        icon="${codename1.icon}"
        vendor="${codename1.vendor}"
        subtitle="${codename1.secondaryTitle}"

        targetType="iphone"
        certificate="${codename1.ios.debug.certificate}"
        certPassword="${codename1.ios.debug.certificatePassword}"
        provisioningProfile="${codename1.ios.debug.provision}"
        appid="${codename1.ios.appid}"
        />
</target>
```

Naturally you would need to do the flip-side of that for Android and other targets.